# Need to transform a column with numbers to datetime format

Tags: regex, r, time, format

I have these data from my `dataset` two columns: times and meters.the column time appear in this format:

```
time     
 321    
 937    
1541    
 354    
1012
```

I need to report the column `time` in a time format. `hh:mm`.(example `03:21`)
But i do not need the date. If I execute as follow it does not work well because it applies that time to all the column. how can I fix it?

```
dataset$time<- strptime("01/01/2013 16:21",format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

Comment: Can you tell us in which coding language please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions in `sub`:

```
dataset$time <- sub("(..)$", ":\\1", dataset$time)
# [1] "3:21"  "9:37"  "15:41" "3:54"  "10:12"
```

Comment: but doing in this way my dataset column is always the same. it doe not modify the entire column format